# react-router-dom switching between 5000 routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I have a reactJS application where I have about 5000 routes and every load of a link in the browser lasts about 6 seconds. If I reduce the number of routes the time needed to load the page decreases.

Routes are declared in App.js like this:

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
          <Switch>
              <Route path='/' exact={true} component={Home}/>
              <Route path='/Department47352List' exact={true} component={Department47352List}/>
              <Route path='/Department47352Edit/:id' exact={true} component={Department47352Edit}/>
              <Route path='/DepartmentType47353List' exact={true} component={DepartmentType47353List}/>
              <Route path='/DepartmentType47353Edit/:id' exact={true} component={DepartmentType47353Edit}/> 
              ........
```

Is there something I can do to optimize the speed without decreasing the number of routes?

I read on the official react-router-dom [page](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/router-components/router) that "You probably never need to render a  manually."
Is it wrong to do so or is it just a recommendation?

I can definitely reduce the number of routes to 1-2 thousand but still, I think the loading time is too high for 5000 routes, I can run a DB query on a table with over 10 thousand records much faster, in my mind the routes should work faster that any DB... so maybe there is something wrong in my approach?

Comment: That many routes seems a little insane, are you sure you need so many? (Even 1-2 thousand is still vastly more than nearly any regular site would use) Surely using patterns like: `/Department/:deptId/List/:id` it could be reduced to less than that.

Comment: I'm trying to migrate my old JAVA swing application to reactJS so my first idea was to make 2 routes for every object I have in the old app, one route for the edit form and one route for the table form.
I have 2500 objects and this is how I ended up with 5000 routes.

Comment: Wow 1k plus routes, it looks like it could need a different architecture to deal with such scale, can any one suggest a architecture